# find the value of $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!-2)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

let $c$ and $r  \in \mathbb{Z}$ . Define  $B(c,r)=\{(c+kr)|k \in \mathbb{Z}\}$  As  $c$  varies   over all integer  and $r$ over all positive integer.The set $B(c,r)$  form a  basis for a  topology on $\mathbb{Z}$. Does the following $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!-2)^2$  exist with respect  to this  topology ?

If so ,then find the value  of $\lim_{n \to \infty} (n!-2)^2$?

I think yes because $\mathbb{Z}$ induce the  discrete  topology $\implies \lim_{n \to \infty} (n!-2)^2=\{0\}$

Comment: The limit is definitely not $0$. To see this, consider the sequence modulo $3$ (it is eventually constant), and the neighbourhood $B(0, 3)$ of $0$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera i edited

Comment: Do you have a proof of that the topology generated by $\{B(c,r) : c \in \mathbb Z, \, r \in \mathbb Z^+\}$ is the discrete topology?

Comment: No @azif00 Actually ,Im  using the logic  that the   Every metric is topology  Consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with its usual metric, $d(a, b) = |a − b|$.In this metric, every subset is open. So the topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ induced by $d$ is the discrete topology

Comment: But who says that the particular topology the question is about (generated by the $B(c,r)$s) is induced by a metric at all?

Comment: That my assumption@Troposphere

Comment: @Troposphere Who says? [Resző László Lovas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evenly_spaced_integer_topology), apparently. :-)

Comment: It does not induce the discrete topology.

Comment: This is the Furstenberg topology. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furstenberg%27s_proof_of_the_infinitude_of_primes

Comment: For readers curious about which metric produces this, the Wikipedia article linked by @TheoBendit just appeals to Urysohn's metrization theorem, but following the links from there leads to a concrete definition: $$ d(a,b) = \frac{1}{\max\{ k \in \mathbb N\cup\{\infty\} : 0<n\le k \Rightarrow n\mid(a-b)\}} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: If $\ a\in B(c,r)\ $, then $\ a\equiv c\pmod{r}\ $ and $\ B(c,r)=$$B(a,r)=$$a+r\mathbb{Z}\ $.  So if $\ a=\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow\infty}(n!-2)^2\ $, then for any $\ r\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\ $ you must have $\ a\equiv(n!-2)^2\pmod{r}\ $ for all sufficiently large $\ n\ $.